# Understanding shift in Q values?

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection, analog-to-digital, embedded-systems

Can any one help me understand why there is a shift in Q values? It seems there is a DC offset/bias. How do I remove it or set it accordingly to make it equal to the I values/waveform? I am using a custom HW with LMS7002m 
RF chip.
I am generating a single frequency sine wave at 2.47GHz using the internal test signal generator. I am attaching the plots I vs sample, Q vs sample , I vs Q.
[image]
[image]
[image]

However if I enable the DCLOOP_STOP in register 0x040C, I get the following plot. The Q values get adjusted after 61250 samples. This remains fixed each time I run, the Q values get adjusted around 61250 samples I am not sure where this value comes from and why is this behaviour.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? I suggest contacting Applications Engineering at Lime Microsystems. They would be in the best position to help you.

Comment: This is possibly how long it takes the chip to measure its own DC bias and then attempt to adjust it to zero.  There may be a way to extract this value from the chip and set it again after power up, but that may or may not work as the bias might be affected by temperature and supply voltage, etc.

Comment: Typical use case might be to throw away samples until after the chip warms up and self calibrates.